# How to use Magento 2 loader widget?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

I would like to show a loader using the Magento's default loader widget on my ajax call. When user clicks the submit button I would like to show the loader for 1 second and then hide it.

I am using something like this :

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'mage/loader',

    ], function ($, loader) {
        $(function () { // to ensure that code evaluates on page load

           $.ajax({
             ... 
            })
```

Comment: Quick tip, if a require JS file is required on page load add `domReady!` as a dependency rather than the jQuery function method. If you do it with a jQuery function other modules will not be aware of the page load dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impressively simple:

```
 $('body').trigger('processStart');
```

And to remove it

```
$('body').trigger('processStop');
```

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/web/mage/loader.js).

**Result:**

[image]

**Note on loading scripts after page load**

Quick tip, if a require JS file is required on page load add domReady! as a dependency rather than the jQuery function method. If you do it with a jQuery function other modules will not be aware of the page load dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this assuming I did $('body').loader()  before? .

Comment: Nope, I just tested it out in one of my JS files that has never used the loader before. I didn't even need to load it as a dependency. I'm impressed.

Comment: I believe the JS is already initialised in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml` as it contains `data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}...` on the body tag.

Comment: If the answer works for you please mark it as accepted, internet points ftw

Comment: Weirdly , this didn't work for me. But this did: $('body').loader({}); $('body').loader('show'); @BenCrook

Comment: Interesting, what version of Magento 2 are you on? I'm on 2.1.8

Comment: Hi @BenCrook mine is 2.1.7